# Node JS: How to set template engine in krakenjs

Tags: node.js, templates, pug, kraken.js

I don't know how to set jade template in kraken js, can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your config/app.json, there´s "view engines". Uncomment it and add your own template module (you have to npm install it first of course). You may also have to change the "express" config to use Jade.

Below is an example of a config to use ejs as a view engine:

```
"view engines": {
    "html": {
        "module": "ejs",
        "renderer": "__express"
    }
},

"express": {
    "view engine": "html"
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/paypal/kraken-js/issues/94).